# Why do I get "SyntaxError: 'invalid syntax'" with this "else" statement?

Tags: python

I am trying to define a function in Python but I keep getting "SyntaxError: 'invalid syntax'":

```
def Change_in_price(x):
    if x > 0 :
        return 'increase'
    elif x == 0 :
        return 'no change'
    else x < 0 :
        return 'decrease'
```

What is the problem?

Comment: else has to be alone

Answer (score 2):

You can use either:

```
def Change_in_price(x):
    if x > 0 :
        return 'increase'
    elif x == 0 :
        return 'no change'
    else:
        return 'decrease'
```

or this:

```py
def Change_in_price(x):
    if x > 0 :
        return 'increase'
    elif x == 0 :
        return 'no change'
    elif x < 0 :
        return 'decrease'
```

Answer (score 1):

`else` is a backup is does not need a condition to be executed.

```py
def Change_in_price(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 'increase'
    elif x == 0:
        return 'no change'
    else:  # Else does not need  a condition
        return 'decrease'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def change_in_price(x):
   if x > 0 :
       return 'increase'
   elif x == 0 :
       return 'no change'
   else :
       return 'decrease'
```